# Odd behavior of input="file" tab not allowing multiple image selection on Android

Tags: android, html, gallery

I have an HTML form page that includes the following lines:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
 <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" accept="image/*" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory=""/> 
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It is intended to allow a user to select a **folder** of images, instead of individual image files.  This works correctly on my desktop PC.  It allows me to select the *folder* where my images are, instead of selecting individual image files.

Now I need to have this work on Android tablets.  The problem is, on Android, this opens up a little folder tree, the user taps tree nodes "camera"/image and the photo thumbnails in the gallery are displayed on the right hand side, then the user is **unable** to select multiple images (or even one image).  What happens is, the user single taps (or double taps, or long taps) an image, and the images view immediately closes and the user is returned to the form web page, and the input control says "No file selected". The exact same behavior is manifested in the built-in Android browser and Chrome for Android.

How can I allow the user to either select just the folder where the images are, or, select all the images (or even one image at this point), so that the input control knows that all photos (or all photos, highlighted or checkmarked, or what ever) are selected for upload on an Android device?

(Or is there some unknown action the user needs to take while in the Gallery, like tap something, or long tap something, to achieve this?)  Thanks in advance for any help you provide.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  It turns out that Android is unable to select a directory, so it ends up in a lame condition where it simply displays the directory, but won't let you select the directory.

The solution is to REMOVE all the "directory" attributes.  So the input line shd be as follows:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" accept="image/*" multiple />
```

This is understood by Android and will allow you to select multiple files as expected.